# How to subtract two hours format in hours format in moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs, angular-moment, moment-timezone

```
let dayDuration = "23:59:59";
let anotherhour ="04:00:00";

moment.duration(moment(dayDuration, "hh:mm:ss").diff(anotherhour));
```

How to incremant in previous value in a loop:

suppose first iteration duration value as 10 and second iteration duration value 30 it should add as 40.

```
     hasEvnets.map(x=>{
var dayDuration = x.startTime;
var anotherHour=x.endTime;
     var remainingtime+= moment.duration(moment(dayDuration, "hh:mm:ss").diff(anotherhour));
        });
```

And

```
    moment(moment("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment("18:00:00", "HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss");
    moment(moment("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment("18:00:00", "HH:mm:ss"))).utc().format("HH:mm:ss"); -06:00:00
which produces 00:00:00 as o/p but i need -18:00:00 how to do that formatting.
```

In C# , which works fine.

```
 var dayDuration = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 00).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime("2019-02-01 18:00:00").TimeOfDay);
            Console.WriteLine(dayDuration);
```

And I have tried this .

let n = moment.duration(moment("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment("18:00:00", "HH:mm:ss")));

console.log(n);

[image]

I need below format.
18:00:00

http://jsfiddle.net/5103y2du/4/

Atlast I have found solution but the solution is not good.

let n = moment.duration(moment("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment("18:00:00", "HH:mm:ss")));

working fine

```
let z = n.hours();
let y = n.minutes();
let u = n.seconds();
console.log(z+":0"+y+":0"+u);
```

--
Not working

Need the same by using moment

```
console.log(moment(n.hours).format("hh:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `anotherhour` is a `string`, so it's not working properly.

Try this:

```
moment(moment(dayDuration, "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(anotherhour, "HH:mm:ss"))).utc().format('HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Thanks man one more thing after getting the below result i need to convert it to minutes how to do that. 19:59:59 as minutes format

Comment: use `moment.duration` and its `.asMinutes()`

Comment: `moment.duration(moment(dayDuration, "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(anotherhour, "HH:mm:ss"))).asMinutes()`

Comment: suppose first iteration duration value as 10 and second iteration duration value 30 it should add as 40.

var x+= moment.duration(moment(dayDuration, "hh:mm:ss").diff(anotherhour));

Comment: why this code produce wrong o.p `moment(moment("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment("18:00:00", "HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss"); which produces 00:00:00 as o.p instead of -18:00:00`

Comment: one issue  `
let n = moment.duration(moment("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment("16:00:00", "HH:mm:ss")));

console.log(moment(n));` when run this moment object produce correct output when i format it it console.log(moment(n.asSeconds()).format("H:mm:ss")); produces wrong result.http://jsfiddle.net/5103y2du/4/